# При создании std::regex выбрасывает исключение std::regex_error

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, std-regex

при попытке создания регулярного выражения выкидывается ошибка **Microsoft C++ exception: std::regex_error at memory location ....**

```
std::regex re("\[((\w+\s)+)?\w+-((([a-z]+\s)+)?[a-z]+:)+\]");
```

Работает только эта часть:

```
std::regex re("\[((\w+\s)+)?\w+-\]");
```

Comment: Вариант вспомнить, что \ — управляющая последовательность, не рассматривали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не забывайте, что все, что в строке начинается с обратной косой черты — управляющие последовательности, так что чтоб получить такую косую черту в строке, ее надо удваивать, типа

```
"\\[((\\w+\\s)+)?\\w+-((([a-z]+\\s)+)?[a-z]+:)+\\]"
```

Ну, или использовать raw string

```
R"(\[((\w+\s)+)?\w+-((([a-z]+\s)+)?[a-z]+:)+\])"
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает.